# How to remove 'blank' files from Visual Studio when debugging Classic ASP

Tags: debugging, vbscript, asp-classic, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

At my current workplace, we have a piece of software that uses Classic ASP. Whenever I try and debug the application by putting in a 'stop' command, it takes ages for Visual Studio to load up the debug mode, normally at least 30 minutes. This is the time from attaching the process from your browser to it actually making the 'stop' break point available to debug.

I believe it takes this long because it loads up lots of 'blank' files in the Solution Explorer:
[image: Blank files under the main script files]

How do I remove these 'blank' files? By the looks of things, they don't contain any content and are previous instances of debugging files which have been saved, as when I save an ASP file it seems to create more of them. I'm using IIS version 10 (on Windows 10). Other colleagues get the same problem, although it loads a lot quicker for them.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to delete the files from windows explorer?

Comment: @WorkSmarter The files don't appear in Windows Explorer as they are under the 'Script Documents' part of the Solution Explorer, not the physical files themselves. One thing I have noticed though that is if I use Visual Studio 2015, there are a lot less 'blank' files so it loads instantly, so it must be a Visual Studio specific setting that needs adjusting.

Comment: @user1779775, Could you share a simple project sample using one drive here? Do you debug it like the steps here: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio, if you create a new blank solution, and then add all project files to this blank solution, and then debug it again, how about the result?